# How to get button to invoke form

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Another newbie here. I took this code from old site page and want to use it on a page in a new WP site.
I put the appropriate HEAD info in the HEADER section on WP, and the following script on the page, but I can't seem to get the button to invoke the form itself.

Would greatly appreciate help.

```
<center><form><input type="button" id="feedback-button" class="button" value="Open Support Ticket" /></form></center>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {


    // ==== custom trigger function ====
    triggerFunction : function( showCollectorDialog ) {
        $('#feedback-button').on( 'click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            showCollectorDialog();
        });

    }

});
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want the button to submit the form, there is absolutely no need to use JavaScript for that; that's the browser's default behavior. However, you'll need to make sure that all your inputs *including the submit button* are in the *same `form` element*. You'll also need to make sure that that `form` element has an `action` attribute and a `method` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the custom trigger event is calling to showCollectorDialog()

Do you also have the code for showCollectorDialog?

You might want to try adding an alert message to see if the function is getting invoked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = $.extend(window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS, {


// ==== custom trigger function ====
triggerFunction : function( showCollectorDialog ) {
    $('#feedback-button').on( 'click', function(e) {
        alert("Yes, the button is getting executed!");
        e.preventDefault();
        showCollectorDialog();
        alert("No, looks like I passed the showCollectorDialog and is not working");
    });

}

});
</script>
```

Other options include having some code in the button that is an onClick event like...

```
<center><form><input type="button" id="feedback-button" onClick="functionName()" class="button" value="Open Support Ticket" /></form></center>
```

The onClick can be used to fireoff some sort of function depending on the action you need. I can't tell exactly what the code is doing, but perhaps is opening a pop-up window for a support ticket?

Really we need some more details, but see if the above helps you at least trouble shoot down what is happening to get started.